# Maintaining a multiple column layout on phone with bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm surprised that I couldn't find another question that deals with this.

Basically, how could one maintain multiple columns on a phone with bootstrap 2.3.2?

Here's a simple outline of my code: http://www.bootply.com/81265

It's fine on a desktop, but occupies way too much vertical space when each column breaks to it's own row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your content inside the grid columns and apply large and small classes for each media.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the responsive layout http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive by changing your stylesheet from this

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to the following

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I don't see anything after "the following"

Comment: Thanks. The issue though is that I'm building on top of a theme, so don't have the option of switching stylesheets.